# How to query large sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom, caml

I have a list that contains tens of thousands of items.

I have tried to limit the query using a `where` clause, like this:

```
var list = Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(title);

string query = $@"<Query>
<Where>
    <Lt>
        <FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Integer'>100</Value>
    </Lt>
</Where>
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='true' /></OrderBy>
</Query>";

var camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = query;

var items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
Context.Load(items);
Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

But I'm getting `SPQueryThrottledException` anyway:

> The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list
>   view threshold enforced by the administrator.

How do I query large sp list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your CAML query and use pagination using `ListItemCollectionPosition` as well as set the RowLimit value.

Try and modify the below sample code:

```
var list = Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(title);
ListItemCollectionPosition position = null;

try
{
    do
    {
        string query = $@"<View> 
            <ViewFields>
                <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
            </ViewFields>       
            <Query>
                <Where>
                    <Lt>
                        <FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Integer'>100</Value>
                    </Lt>
                </Where>
            <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy>
            </Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";

        var camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = query;


        var items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
        Context.Load(items);
        Context.ExecuteQuery();
        position = items.ListItemCollectionPosition;

        foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
            Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", listItem["Title"]);
    }
    while (position != null);

}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

Updated CAML query as per comments:

```
string query = $@"<View>                            
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Geq>
                <FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Integer'>1</Value>
            </Geq>
            <Leq>
                <FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Integer'>1000</Value>
            </Leq>                                        
        </And>
    </Where>
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' /></OrderBy>
</Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
```

Comment: This works, but when I remove the where condition, it throws the SPQueryThrottledException. I don't know where the ID's starts.
Is there any way how to retrieve first 100 items?

Comment: Try with the updated CAML query. ID of the list item will always be greater than or equal to 1. Its by design, we will then order the items by their created date. This gives us only 100 results ordered by their creation date.

Comment: What if first 5000 items is deleted? Is sharepoint really that stupid?

Comment: You can query on the created date then. I believe i have answered the question that was asked originally. It kinda depends on you what you want to filter out. ID is the best and fastest as it will always be indexed/ Related links - [Overcoming the List View Threshold in SharePoint CAML queries](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1076854/Overcoming-the-List-View-Threshold-in-SharePoint-C) and [Working with large lists in SPO](https://davidlozzi.com/2017/03/13/how-to-work-with-large-lists-in-office-365-sharepoint-online/). Please mark it as answer if it helped you